# How does work injection in TypeScript Class?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is the following TypeScript class:

```
class RaceList {
    raceService: RaceService;
    races: Array<string>;

    constructor(raceService: RaceService) {
        // the interesting part is `: RaceService`
        this.raceService = raceService;
        this.raceService.list()
            .then(races => this.races = races);
      }
}
```

How does work this construction: `this.raceService.list()` if I dont have initialization of class like this: `raceService = new RaceService()`?

Comment: `RaceService` is Angular Service and you don't need to make initialization. Angular Services are different from Classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [this](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/20/Angular-2-Services-Tutorial---Understanding-&-Creating-Them) tutorial:

"An Angular 2 service is simply a javascript function, along with its associated properties and methods, that can be included (via dependency injection) into Angular 2 components. They allow you to develop code for specific tasks that can be used in those components."

They do not require initialization when injected (it is done on its own), they have a single state and simply require to be injected in a given component.

Here's a better approach:

```
class RaceList {
    races: Array<string>;

    constructor(private raceService: RaceService) {          
        raceService.list()
            .then(races => this.races = races);
    }
}
```

As you can see you do not need to save the service's value in a class variable as it is set to private, it can be used in any method in `RaceList` by calling `this.raceService`.

Comment: Actually you do need to save the service in a class variable to use it anywhere except inside the constructor. The usual way to do this is to add `public` or `private` to the parameter declaration: `constructor(private raceService: RaceService)` which is just a shorthand for declaring a private attribute and then initialising it in the constructor.

Comment: That's a very good point, I forgot to define `private` in the declaration. Thank you.

Comment: I still dont understand how does work injection without creating instance of object, or is it just function, not class?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntactic sugar of typescript,
Instead of:

```
private raceService: RaceService;

constructor() {
    this.raceService = new RaceService;
}
```

You simply do this:

```
constructor(private raceService: RaceService) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, Angular does the initialization and give you the initialized instance through your component's constructor.

If your service itself needs some others services in its constructor, Angular initializes this others services, provide them to your service constructor, and then provide your service to your component.